# To find a extremal point of a function with parameters

Tags: functions, derivatives, parametric, extremal-graph-theory

I have a function $$f(x) = (x-5m)(x+m)^2$$
I have tried to find the extremal points of this function (and then find if it's local maxima or minima). That means I need to find the ***x*** of derivative.
The derivative is: $$-9m^2 - 6m + 3x^2$$
From there I tried to find what's the value of *x*:
\begin{align}
\ -9m^2 - 6mx + 3x^2 = 0\\
\ 3x^2 - 6mx = 9m^2 \\
\ x^2 - 2mx = 3m^2 \\
\ x(x-2m) = 3m^2 \\
\ x= \frac{3m^2}{x-2m}
\end{align}

I checked with WolframAlpha that **x needs to be *3m* or *-m***, but I don't success to solve it. Someone that can help to get to this two answers? [WolframAlpha problem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-9m%CB%862%20-%206mx%20%2B%203x%CB%862%20%3D%200).

Comment: You have quadratic equation for $x$: $x^2 - 2mx  - 3m^2 = 0$. Solve it.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza ohhh! Didn't look it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the quadratic formula, the solutions of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are given by
$$x_\pm = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
and in your case $a=1, b=-2m, c=-3m^2$ so you get
$$x_\pm = \frac{2m \pm \sqrt{4m^2+12m^2}}{2}
        = \frac{2m \pm \sqrt{16m^2}}{2}
        = \frac{2m \pm 4m}{2} = -m \text{ or } 3m.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You  have made  a  mistake.

$\Large x=\frac{3m^{2}}{x-2m}$ does not really give a value of  $x$.

Both  sides  have  $x$.

This is $x^{2}-2mx-3m^{2}=0$.

> Now use **Sridharacharya's Formula**  for  quadratic  equation $$x=\frac{-b\pm {\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}}{2a}$$  for  an  equation  like $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$

and  you  will  get $3m$  or $-m$  as  answers.